# Shell cript check port and restart service

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

I want to script check port:
the first check port open or close
If port close.after check PID for service on port.If exist PID, kill PID, restart service
have message on file log.

Comment: What have you tried thus far, what do you mean by "check port" ?  If the port is closed how can you get the services PID?   If you provide a more precise question, I can probably help you - conceptually what you are trying to do can be done with tools like "logger" for logging, netcat to check if a port is open or fuser to check the process ID associated with a port, but its hard to put these together without knowing the service, as it appears you are asking to "test for a negative", and thus you can't get some information you need from the negative result and need to look elsewhere for it.

Comment: i think Port close but PID can exist because service hang.:D

Comment: Surely the solution would be to check if the service is working (if its TCP you could use nc (netcat), and then if its not working send a command to "killall" the process ?

Comment: i was find tutorial in http://bash.cyberciti.biz/monitoring/monitor-unix-linux-network-services/
 but not check PID and kill service.